# How do I use write with stringstream?

Tags: c++, stl, vector, stringstream

I have a `vector<char>` of data which I want to write into `std::stringstream`.

I tried:

```
my_ss.write(vector.data(), vector.size());
```

...but it seems to put nothing into `my_ss` which I declared as follows:

`std::stringstream my_ss(  std::stringstream::binary);`

Why write is not working (app does not crash and compiles with 0 errors, 0 warnings)?

Comment: Show us some actual code.  (And `std::basic_ios::binary` doesn't have any effect on a `stringstream`.  They're always "binary".)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the "how do I do it" you can use a `std::ostream_iterator`:

```
std::copy(vector.begin(), vector.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(my_ss));
```

Complete example:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  std::vector<char> vector(60, 'a');
  std::ostringstream my_ss;
  std::copy(vector.begin(), vector.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(my_ss));
  std::cout << my_ss.str() << std::endl;
}
```

You could also just use that to construct a `string` directly, without going via a `stringstream` at all:

```
std::string str(vector.begin(), vector.end()); // skip all of the copy and stringstream
```

Comment: This answer may give a wrong idea as if `stringstream::write()` cannot be used. Indeed, the OP's problem seems to be not with `stringstream::write()`, but with `std::stringstream my_ss(  std::stringstream::binary);` , which can be fixed to `std::stringstream my_ss (std::stringstream::out | std::stringstream::binary);` as the other answers suggest.

Answer (score 5):

Though you haven't given any code, it sounds like you probably just wrote:

```
std::stringstream my_ss (std::stringstream::binary);
```

If you wish to write to a stringstream you need to combine the flag `std::stringstream::out` in the constructor.  If I'm right, then you would see things working fine if you changed this to:

```
std::stringstream my_ss (std::stringstream::out | std::stringstream::binary);
```

(Obviously if you wish to read from that stringstream you need to add `std::stringstream::in`)

**UPDATE** Now that you've given your code...yup, this is your specific problem.  Note @awoodland's point about the fact that you can just construct a string from a vector of chars instead (if that's the only thing you were planning on doing with this stream.)

Answer (score 4):

The default parameter for the mode of stringbuf in stringstream is out|in.

```
explicit basic_stringstream(ios_base::openmode _Mode =
    ios_base::in | ios_base::out)
    : _Mybase(&_Stringbuffer),
        _Stringbuffer(_Mode)
    {   // construct empty character buffer
    }
```

You need to add stringstream::out if you pass something explicitly like stringstream:binary

Or just use std::ostringstream