# C++ - How to initialize an output stream to either a stringstream or null stream?

Tags: c++, stream

The only solution I can think of is:

```
bool shouldLog = ...
std::stringstream oss;

if (!shouldLog)
{
    oss.rdbuf(0);
}

// do stuff...

if (shouldLog)
{
    MethodThatLogsStuff(oss.str());
}
```

Is there some way to do something like:

```
std::stringstream oss(shouldLog ? use normal string buffer : use null buffer);
```

Comment: It's kind of hard to understand what you want here, C++ streams must have a valid buffer at all times otherwise their `badbit` is set and any operation will fail. You can set `basic_filebuf`s to perform unbuffered input and output, but not `basic_stringbuf`s as there's nothing to fall back on.

Comment: This is one of the problems boost::iostreams is supposed to solve: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html. It's got a concept of "null sink" which you can use the way you want.

Comment: Please Go through [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8169120/3110262)